# Define the default plot range

Tags: plot, range, sympy

Can I define the **default** range of all my SymPy plots once and for all? Yes, I like the (-5, 5) default range of the M-word better than SymPy's (-10, 10).

Comment: Sympy is open source, if you are really really annoyed by its defaults, you can change these lines in your local copy of the source code.

Comment: Currently, this  default is set in [sympy/plotting/plot.py line 2578](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/56b1c08619dc4c4b53567fca2fffb9ca7ca6445a/sympy/plotting/plot.py#L2578) `default_range = Tuple(-10, 10)` and also on line 2617 depending on whether the free variable is explicitly given.